# Need some ideas to improve when run on aws-beanstalk instance of Linux type when creating webdriver instance in Robotframework

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, robotframework, head, headless-browser

Need little help to improve the test design:
Current design>>
Suitefilename.robot

```
*** Settings****
Suite Setup     Run Keywords  Launch Web Browser    ${URL}    ${Browser}  AND  Connect to ProjectDB  
Suite Teardown  Run Keywords  Close All Browsers     Disconnect From Database

Test Setup        Common wait

***Testcases****
TC1:
    Login into application
    Action1
    [Teardown] Logout of application

TC2:
   Login into application
    Action2
    [Teardown] Logout of application
```

### Pageclass.robot

```
***Keywords***
Launch Web Browser    ${URL}    ${Browser}  
       [Arguments]    ${URL}    ${Browser}   
        Run Keyword If      '${BROWSER}' == 'HeadlessChrome'      Open Headless Chrome Browser and Launch Url  ${URL}
        ...     ELSE IF     '${BROWSER}' == 'HeadlessFirefox'     Open Headless Firefox and Launch Url    ${URL}
        ...     ELSE         Open Browser    url= ${URL.${Environment}}    browser=${BROWSER}
    Set Selenium Speed    ${DELAY}
    Maximize Browser Window    
    LOG TO CONSOLE    Label verified on LoginPage
    SLEEP    3s

Open Headless Chrome Browser and Launch Url
     [Arguments]    ${url}
     ${chrome_options}=    Evaluate  sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()   sys, selenium.webdriver
     Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    test-type
     Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-extensions
     Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    headless
     Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    disable-gpu
     Call Method    ${chrome_options}    add_argument    no-sandbox
     Create Webdriver    Chrome    chrome_options=${chrome_options}   executable_path=/opt/chromedriver
     Log to console   HeadlessChrome has chromeoptions>test-type/disableextenstions/headless/disable_gpu/no_to_sanbox
     Set Window Size    1920    1080
     #Log to console   Setting Selenium speed to 3s
     #Set Selenium Speed   3s
     Go To     url= ${URL.${Environment}}

Open Headless Firefox and Launch Url
     [Arguments]    ${url}
     ${firefox_options}=     Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].firefox.webdriver.Options()   sys, selenium.webdriver
     Call Method    ${firefox_options}   add_argument    -headless
     #Call Method    ${firefox_options}    add_argument    --disable-gpu
     Log to console   HeadlessFirefox has firefoxoptions>headless
     Create Webdriver    Firefox    firefox_options=${firefox_options}
     Set Window Size    1920    1080
     #Log to console   Setting Selenium speed to 3s
     #Set Selenium Speed   3s
     Go To    url= ${URL.${Environment}}                    

Connect to ProjectDB  
     Connect To Database    psycopg2   ${prj_DBName}    ${prj_DBUser}   ${prj_DBPass}   ${prj_DBHost}   ${prjPort}

Disconnect from DB
    Disconnect From Database

Common wait
     sleep 5s
```

---

With current design the observations are:-
When run on local machine:-

TC1:-Login ,AC1, Logout
Result: Pass

TC2:- Login,AC2 ,Logout
Result: Pass

TC3:- Login,AC3 ,Logout
Result: Pass

On Aws Linux instance:-

TC1:-Login ,AC1, Logout
Result: Pass

TC2:- Login failed
Result: fail

TC3:- Login pass/fail,AC3 ,Logout
Result: Pass/failure

Test suite to support cross browser and cross platform.
Wanted to get some thoughts on how to improve the design to get same output and consistent results as run on local machine.

Comment: "fail" isn't a useful description. It's failing for a reason, Can you include that reason in your question?

Comment: Unable to find Login page elements mostly the  Username element and its Locator not found.

Comment: And when it fails because it can't find the username element, is that because it's really not there _at the time the keyword runs_? Maybe the browser is just slower and you're not giving the page a chance to finish loading.

Comment: Thanks, @bryan Oakley I did consider those factors and added some more time. What else should be considered?

Comment: Log the [HTML source](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Log%20Source) and/or [take screenshots](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Capture%20Page%20Screenshot)

Comment: Thanks @kootstra, I disabled taking screenshots for some reason but will enable and watch.